# Telegram bot генерирующий рандомные пароли пишет все символы отдельно

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

```py
import telebot
import random
import config
 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.configurate)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_password(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'генерировать пароль':
        vault =
'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0'
        password = ""
        for a in range(8):
            password = random.choice(vault)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, password)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка')

bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```

Сделал Telegram bot, генерирующего рандомные пароли, а он пишет каждый символ отдельным сообщением.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в этих строчках:

```
for a in range(8):
    password = random.choice(vault) 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, password)
```

Вы, тем самым, отправляете каждый символ.

**Решение**:

Вам нужно не отправлять, а добавлять в строку к предыдущим символам:

```
password = "" 
for a in range(8): 
    password += random.choice(vault)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, password)
```

Вывод в чат:

```
,T,ER,k,
```

Также, посоветую избавиться от '`,`' в пароле, например, так:

```
password = "" 
for a in range(8): 
    password += random.choice(vault)
password = password.replace(',', '')
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, password)
```

Вывод:

```
aUMhp
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решило проблему!

Comment: @Dimyni если ответ помог, то, пожалуйста, оцените его.

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю решение с использованием `str.join(list)`, который соединяет все элементы списка через строку-разделитель, у которой вызван метод.

```
import telebot
import random
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.configurate)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) 
def get_password(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'генерировать пароль':
        vault = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0'
        password = "".join([random.choice(vault) for a in range(8)])
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, password)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка')

bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)'''
```